# How to do the correct way to encrypt to AES256 using CryptoJs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, encryption, cryptojs

Hi i'm new to React Native,
i can encrypt the data in the PHP but not with React Native using Crypto JS. (result in JS always different, the correct one is from the PHP)

This is the example in PHP :

```
<?php

$data = 'my1234567';
$iv = 'yourivare1234567';
$key = '356d9abc7532ceb0945b615a622c3370';

$abc = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0,  $iv);
var_dump($abc);
// result is : string(24) "9EF/QLpR+o/KrVueiI4L0g=="
```

Now i try to replicate it in my React Native apps using Crypto JS.
But the result always different, where i'm expecting the result using hardcoded data and iv like above is : "9EF/QLpR+o/KrVueiI4L0g=="

Below is the source code in JS :

```
const data = 'my1234567';
const iv = 'yourivare1234567';
const key = '356d9abc7532ceb0945b615a622c3370';

const fkey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
const fiv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);

const enc = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, md5key, {
        iv: fiv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
});

const final = enc.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log('encrypted password: ' , final) // result is kYLFiwI1IDZcFfsKsbrbzg==
```

Can somebody help on this?

Thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fkey` and `fiv` must be parsed using the UTF8 encoder. `md5key` is not defined and must be replaced by `fkey`:

```js
const data = 'my1234567';
const iv = 'yourivare1234567';
const key = '356d9abc7532ceb0945b615a622c3370';

const fkey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
const fiv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);

const enc = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, fkey, {
        iv: fiv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
});

const final = enc.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log('encrypted password: ' , final) // result is 9EF/QLpR+o/KrVueiI4L0g==
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Note that (except for testing purposes) no static IV may be used for security reasons.

Comment: Hi @Topaco, noted about the static IV (for testing purpose only). For md5key var i forgot to change back to fkey while debugging :)  So the solution is work thanks! Btw can you explain a little bit why we need to parsing the key and iv with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: @abet - Strings in PHP are simply byte sequences determined by the encoding used. I just assumed the default UTF-8 encoding is applied in your PHP environment, [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset), which requires the same encoder for the CryptoJS code, i.e. UTF8. But also Latin1 (aka ISO-8859-1) would work, since your key and IV consist entirely of alphanumeric characters, for which [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) and [Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) give the same byte sequence.